# vb.NET SQL Query - "Incorrect syntax near >" when filtering float column using parameter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've got an application that, upon the press of a button, should display a list of data filtered by a service abbreviation and, where applicable, a numeric value.

For some reason I cannot get the parameter for the numeric value to work without it causing an exception. The numeric column is 'number_result' and is float data type. This occurs even without a value in the text box, which is set to allow only numeric characters:

```vb
    Private Sub txtResultAbove_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtResultAbove.TextChanged
        Dim digitsOnly As Regex = New Regex("[^\d]")
        txtResultAbove.Text = digitsOnly.Replace(txtResultAbove.Text, "")
    End Sub
```

Initially I tried inserting the parameter as a string given I am looking for >= 50 (as an example), using this as the query:

```vb
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT rq.request_id As 'Request ID', svc.service_abbrev As 'Service', concat(do.dr_first_name, ' ', do.dr_surname) As Doctor, rq.collection_dt as 'Collected', rq.entry_date As 'Received', concat(rqs.number_result, rqs.text_result) as 'Result'

                FROM dbo.requests_services rqs

                LEFT JOIN services      svc ON svc.service_id = rqs.service_id
                LEFT JOIN requests         rq ON rq.request_id = rqs.request_id
                LEFT JOIN doctors          do ON do.doctor_id  = rq.doctor_id
        
                WHERE rqs.number_result @numRes AND rq.entry_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND svc.service_abbrev LIKE @SvcAbb

                    
                ORDER BY rqs.service_id ASC
            ", conn)

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTo.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@numRes", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "=> " + txtResultAbove.Text
                If txtServiceCode.TextLength > 0 Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SvcAbb", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtServiceCode.Text
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SvcAbb", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%"
                End If
```

Thinking it was the way I'd set the parameter value, I then moved the '=>' to the query and left the parameter to be only the texbox value:

```vb
...
WHERE rqs.number_result >= @numRes AND rq.entry_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND svc.service_abbrev LIKE @SvcAbb
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@numRes", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtResultAbove.Text
...
```

Then I thought, maybe it needs to be an integer to work, so I did this:

```vb
Convert.ToInt32(txtResultAbove.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@numRes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtResultAbove.Text
```

And that also didn't work.

The exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '>'.'

What am I doing wrong here? The query works if I replace the parameter with a static string (ie >= 45)

Comment: The syntax error is in the SQL code so show us the SQL code. Show us the FULL SQL code and ONLY the SQL code, not the VB code used to construct it. You can include other information as well, if you think it's relevant, but you MUST include the full, unadulterated SQL code if that is what the question is actually about.

Comment: Just as VB method parameters can be used for values only - not identifiers or operators or anything else - so SQL parameters can only be used for values.

Comment: The point of parameters is to separate *code* from *data*. So don't try to insert code into parameters and expect the database system to treat that as code. In fact, if it did do so, that would immediately render parameters as useless for defeating SQL Injection.

Comment: `=>` should be `>=` And yeah you can't put actual code such as a `>=` operator into a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try these in SQL Server:

```
select *, '>=' using
from (select 1 as col1)  dummy
where col1 >= 0
;
```

That query works fine! Now run this:

```
select *, '=<' using
from (select 1 as col1)  dummy
where col1 =< 0
;
```

The second query will reproduce your error message. `Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

i.e. Don't use `=<`

Comment: btw: I am not advocating that you should continue to concatenate a number with "<=", but I think I have identified why you think you need to do so.